# How do i print this using For nested loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

here is what I am suppose to print using simple concept of NESTED LOOP ONLY..
It's a nested for loop pattern question .
i have been thinking since last 2 hour but i can't come up with a proper solution.
Edit:I am allowed to use if conditions if required.

```
   1 2 3 4
   2 3 4 1
   3 4 1 2
   4 1 2 3
```

i have already tried using different if statements such `i==1 && j==1` then print column etc

Comment: Best solution I can think of is a nested for loop. You need to show effort before people here will help

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: Hint: Use 2 nested for loops with modular arithmetic to print desired values.

Comment: Your sir wants you to do the homework, not because it's too easy or too tough. He wants you to try it yourself and learn. Please don't post homework questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to see the pattern and replicate it in your code. Here is one way to solve this, which can also be used to produce larger matricies (set the `max` variable to a different value):

```
public class main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int max = 5;
    for(int i = 1; i < max; ++i){
        for(int j = i; j < max; ++j)
            System.out.print(" " + j);

        for(int k = 1; k < i; ++k)
            System.out.print(" " + k);

        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output when `max = 5`:

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 1
3 4 1 2
4 1 2 3
```

Output when `max = 7`:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 3 4 5 6 1
3 4 5 6 1 2
4 5 6 1 2 3
5 6 1 2 3 4
6 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: @smitShah No problem. Feel free to upvote my post too. Good luck coding!